# Get the latest approved member

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, membership-provider

I'm using ASP .NET MVC 2.0 with the default membership provider. How would I go about retrieving the name of the latest registered approved member?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell there are no 'out of the box' methods of the `Membership` class that allow you to do this.
You will need to run a custom query or stored procedure against the `aspnet_Membership` table using either ADO.NET or your preferred ORM. The key columns you need to query against are `CreateDate` and `IsApproved`.

Comment: After reading this blog - http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/03/05/38558/ I'm concidering creating my own user table which would contain all the users from the default membership provider tables. This way I can also store additional user information if I need to, would this be a better idea?